# how to get the version of mysql without running anything relate to mysql itself?

Tags: mysql, configuration, automation

there are many ways to retrieve version of a mysql distribution, such as :

- running a SQL statements in the server by:

`select version();`

or

`show global variables like 'version';`

- `mysqld --version`

My scenario would be a precompiled binary MySQL distribution / compiled from source MySQL installation, so acquiring version from system's package manager would be out of the question, additionally for stability and security concern I am not at the privilege of utilizing methods above.

**It might seems a bit odd, but I wonder where these version information are stored, can I extract them just by reading the file? or do I need to somehow dissect the binary to get the info?**

***PROGRESS:***
I noticed that `%VERSION%` variable is a system variable according to this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_version), and is stored in information_schema/performance_schema, then I looked into /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema, but there is only a `global_variable.frm` file which does not contain any data, while I can perfectly fetch the version information by

```
use performance_schema; 
select * from global_variables where variable_name = 'version';
```

[1] performance_schema, according to this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-variable-table-migration.html) also stores systems variable.

Comment: Are we talking Linux or a broader solution?

Comment: Also, should this work on one server or do you need multiple servers with potentially different distros or even OSes?

Comment: Have you tried just ```$ mysqld -V``` ?

Comment: @Gnudiff generally I would prefer the broader the better, but currently I'm considering Linux,  and this solution should work on various conditions, in other words, multiple servers.

Comment: @ALex_hha this I stated in the title, an operation related to mysql itself, is undesired.

Comment: And what the root of such restrictions?

Comment: @ALex_hha the root is hard to explain, but the gist of it is avoid touching anything in production.

Comment: What do you mean by "touching" ? If you run ```mysqld -v``` - you won't "touch/break" anything, imho

Comment: @ALex_hha another thing that I didn't make it too obvious is that I don't want to accidentally run anything malicious, as the `mysqld` I invoke could be a fake one planted on system.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to log files then you can read the .err file. It includes a line like this: `14:07:26 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.31-MariaDB) starting as process`.

Also if telnet is allowed you can do this `telnet database_server 3306` and it will display the version as well. If not telnet then nmap can provide similar information but again this depends on your firewall and network setup.

```
# nmap -sV -p 3306 my-data-base-server

Starting Nmap 4.75 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-22 09:51 CET
Interesting ports on my-data-base-server (192.168.xxx.xxx):
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION

3306/tcp open  mysql   MySQL 5.5.5-10.0.33-MariaDB
MAC Address: 5x:5x:00:Fx:8C:03 (QEMU Virtual NIC)

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.33 seconds
```

Comment: to your first solution, which log are you referring to? is it syslog or log of mysql itself? to your second solution, the target mysql installation will very likely to be listenning on other port than 3306,  in other cases the server simply was not started at all, so it will be hard to ensure the successsful version extraction.

Comment: /var/lib/mysql/*.err file.

Comment: there is no such file in my environment, probably because the installation is relatively new. plus did you test it across major mysql releases? to me, extract from log file seems to be an unstable approach.

Answer (score 0):

On  Linux in many cases mysql version installed will be the one that comes with  the actual Linux distro.

Then you can use package query tools to determine the major version.

On Debian based systems:

```
dpkg-query - l "mysql*"
```

On Red Hat and other rpm based ones:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

Depending on whether you need to automate something, this may be enhanced by further filtering and /or specification.

Comment: thanks but this was not the scenario intended. I specifically targeted installation that was compiled from source or precompiled binary distribution. I will edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather a complicated issue. That's by the way, why as a sysadmin I would be quite opposed to running servers not from distro. At the very least after the mysql server is installed it should be started and stopped via usual system mechanisms: sysv init scripts or similar.

1) is the server running and under what (file)name? If you are not dealing with intentional obscuring, you can try something similar to  `ps auxww | grep mysqld` which should show the server binary path. Then again it is possible that under certain binary releases or source compiles it could contain 'mysql-server' or another different binary name instead !

After you got server binary, you can try to decide which version it is, either by :

1) analysing its path: very frequently server is inside a directory which reflects its version number somewhere in the path  ;

2) trying to find its config or other files which might contain version info  somewhere in its path.

3) trying to analyse binary with the `readelf` or similar command and infer its version from some data there.

But note that *none* of the above methods are a guaranteed success.

And will probably fail when applied too broadly (different distros different mysql versions, etc)

PS. I may be mistaken, but I would have thought `mysql --version` would  return the version of mysql CLI client, *not* the server.

Comment: your PS is right, and I have adjusted my questions accordingly. unfortunately that didn't solve my problem.